# Setup openVPN on server and client, I can ping from client to 10.8.0.1

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

But when I check my ip address, it is the same as my local ISP's ip address.

Both services are started on the client(local) and my server.

How can I debug this issue?  where to start?

Both client and server are ubuntu.

Do I have to do anything locally in my 'Devices : Network tools'?

I am looking at the VPN connection, and the only option is VPN, is that the correct one?
I setup a VPN on a server that will forward all local requests to the server.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully got that

Comment: I setup VPN on an ubuntu server, and it is running.  This is will take all requests from my local computer and pass it through the server.

Comment: @user27449 I know what a VPN server is :) So you're saying even though you're connected with the client, you still have your local IP and not  one of your VPN?

Comment: yes that's correct.  every page I visit I get a server not found EXCEPT for google.com works.

Comment: @user27449 You should maybe rephrase and edit your question, telling 1) what you did 2) what you want to do and 3) what happens when you try to do that. I had a hard time guessing what the problem is.

Comment: @slhck how important are the var settings?  what if put in the wrong country will it stop working?

Comment: It might be useful to see your conf file to see how you set the VPN up, it will give us insight into what is going on.